# Reverse the elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've been trying to write a void function called printReverse that takes a double array named d and an int called n as arguments, where n is the number of elements in d. I want printReverse to print the n array values in reverse order. This is what I have so far, but I'm having difficulty declaring arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n
double d[n]

void printReverse(d[], double newArray){
int i;
int j;
for (i=0; j=n-1; i<n; i++; j--;){
   newArray[j]=d[i];
}

printf("%lf\n",newArray);
}
```

Any help in what I'm doing wrong would be very much appreciated.

REVISION: Would this code work

```
void printReverse(double [] d, int n){
    int i;
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%f\n",d[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `double newArray` declares a `double` single value, not an array. Each argument's type must be indicated: `void printReverse( double d[], double newArray[])`

Comment: Where is the `n` argument?

Comment: If the function should just print the array in reverse order, why do you need `newArray` at all? Just loop from `n-1` to `0`, printing the elements.

Comment: Your `for` loop has too many statement blocks. You have five, but it should only have three: (1) initial, (2) loop condition, (3) end-of-each-iteration statement. Use commas: `for (i=0, j=n-1; i < n; i++, j--)`. Are you taking a C class or studying from a book or doing a tutorial? You need to learn the C basics.

Comment: I'm just learning from what is available to me on the internet. I'm very inexperienced.

Comment: There are a lot of fundamental syntax issues with the code. You'll need to go through the tutorials on variable declarations, `for` loops, function declarations, etc. Stackoverflow.com isn't a good place to learn how to program from scratch. I just did a Google search on "C Programming Tutorial" and came up with a bunch of reasonable choices. Here's one describing loops (including `for`): http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html.

Comment: The version of `printReverse()` in REVISION is better, what happens when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

```
//take pointer to array, and size of array as parameters
void printReverse(double* arr,int size){
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%f\n",arr[(size-1)-i]);
        //(size-1)-i will compute the proper index of the array to read backwards.
        //remeber arrays are 0 based meaning that the first member in the array is index 0
    }
}
```

this should do the trick.

EDIT: or if you are trying to reverse the array into a new array and then print...

```
void printReverse(double* arr,double* arr2,int size){
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
        arr2[(size-1)-i]=arr[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%f\n",arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

you will need to have the arrays in the code that calls this function.

so...

```
double arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
double arr2[5];

printReverse(arr,arr2, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both print and store the array in reverse order you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printReverse(double *d, double *newArray, int n){
    int i;
    int j;  

    for (i=0, j=n-1; i<n; i++, j--){
        newArray[i]=d[j];
        printf("%lf\n",newArray[i]);
    }   
}

int main(){

    int n = 4;
    double array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    double newArr[n];

    printReverse(array,newArr,n);
}
```